# Trying to Render Template and Getting ActionView::MissingTemplate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is what I see when I try to load the page (`http://localhost:3000/analytics`):

[image]

I have a file named `_order_charts.html.erb` in my static_pages directory. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= render 'static_pages/order_charts' %>
```

or

```
<%= render partial: 'static_pages/order_charts' %>
```

You do not need to include the underscore, rails is smart like that.

Comment: You have your hash wrong on the partial: `<%= render partial: 'static_pages/order_charts' %>`

Comment: I'll give you the check mark when I'm allowed. Thanks for the help!